# Is there a way to get unique active users in the last 30 days without using group by and losing rows? Maybe window functions?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, looker

I want to calculate the DAU and the MAU (previous 30 days) for my data. I have an elaborate table with user ids and time stamps and many more columns about the transaction.
I have gotten the results but the table is aggregated on the event date, that is one row for each date and then unique user id is calculated for that day as DAU.

this is the code I used to get the aggregated table and it works fine.

```
with dau as
    (select to_date("EventTime") as event_date, count(distinct "UserKey") as dau
     from table
     group by event_date)
   
select event_date, dau, 
             (select count(distinct "UserKey") from table
             where to_date("EventTime") between dateadd(day, -29, dau.event_date) 
             AND dau.event_date) as mau
from dau;
```

The table appears like this

[image: the calculation is exactly the way I need it in this table]

But I do not want to lose any rows in group by aggregation
So, I tried a window function which is working fine for the DAU but not the MAU. Please help me figure out the code.
The code is

```
select to_date("EventTime") as event_date, count(distinct "UserKey") over 
                         (partition by to_date("EventTime")) as repeated_dau
from table;
```

the result looks like this

[image: see how the value remains the same and the rows are not aggregated and the value changes when the date changes in this table].

Now I need this for the MAU which is the count distinct of users for the past 30 days counting from today. Any other method besides window function is also welcome. thanks

Comment: Please provide a tablestructure, exampledata and expected output ...

Comment: @derpirscher the expected output is available in the image link, it is missing the column that i want to figure out. The table structure is a transactional data where we have timestamp, user id, transaction details, cost and other measures like that. hope it answers your question. I am new to stack overflow

Comment: What do you mean by "lose any rows in group by aggregation"  what is wrong with your current approach? It seems to do pretty much what would need (unless I misunderstand your problem) and calculates the MAU for every date in the last 30 days. The only issue might be, if there wasn't a single user on one specific day, there won't be a row for that day. Is that the issue?

Comment: @derpirscher I am actually making an explore in looker so I cannot aggregate the data. I need this logic in sql so I can make an eventual explore in looker where people will have the freedom to filter and aggregate as they want. If you look at the image which is present in the link where it is written " see how the value remains the same" you can see the desired output I want for a repeated mau

Comment: I'm interpreting "losing rows" to mean that once aggregated, you can't get back to the original data (once the egg is boiled, you can't unboil it).  Is that correct?  Because otherwise I don't get the "losing rows" comment unless there's something wrong with your aggregation logic.

Comment: @JimDemitriou i am making an explore for my end users that they can aggregate how they see fit. If i aggregate it to get this metric, I cannot give them the flexibility to make their own aggregations. This logic from SQL will eventually go to a Looker explore.